# Error running PS in .NetCore app - Cannot perform operation because the runspace is not in the 'Opened' state. Current state of runspace is 'Broken'

Tags: powershell, .net-core, runspace

I'm trying to implement a .NetCore 3.1 console app which needs to run PowerShell scripts.  However, when I try run it, I get the following error -

```
Cannot perform operation because the runspace is not in the 'Opened' state. Current state of runspace is 'Broken'.
```

The code that runs the PS script is as below:

```cs
        using System.Management.Automation;

        public async Task<string> RunScript(string scriptToRun)
        {
            // create a new hosted PowerShell instance using the default runspace.
            using PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

            // specify the script code to run.
            ps.AddScript(scriptToRun);

            // execute the script and await the result.
            var pipelineObjects = await ps.InvokeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            // print the resulting pipeline objects to the console.
            var output = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in pipelineObjects)
            {
                output.Append(item.BaseObject.ToString());
            }

            return output.ToString();
        }
```

Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this by creating custom runspace.
Refer to this article - [How to run powershell core scripts from net core applications](https://keithbabinec.com/2020/02/15/how-to-run-powershell-core-scripts-from-net-core-applications/)